# 'DocumentSnapshot' is not a subpyte of type of 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to access images from url saved in FireStore, but I get error from the title

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
        home: StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('images').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
              for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
                return ListWheelScrollView(children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(snapshot.data.documents[i]),
                ]);
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

[image: my firebase collection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a document snapshot inside the Image.Network, to return the url use the square brackets and inside the 'url':

```
Image.network(snapshot.data.documents[i]['url']),
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. I got error "toDouble was called on null" and exception "no adress associated with hostname".

Comment: it's ok now i was offline

Comment: Glad i can help!